# Regular Expression to Match List of File Extensions

Tags: regex, match

I would like to have a regular expression that will match a list of file extensions that are delimited with a pipe `|` such as `doc|xls|pdf`  This list could also just be a single extension such as `pdf` or it could also be a wild card `*` or `?`  I would also like to exclude the `|` at the start or the end of the list and also not match the `\<>/:"` characters.

I have tried the following but it doesn't account for a single `*` wildcard.

`^([^|\\<>\/:"]|[^\\<>:"])[^\/\\<>:"]*[^|\/\\<>:"]$`

I have been on one of the online testers but can't seem to get over the final hurdle.  If someone could point me in the right direction I would be most grateful.

Comment: Would the extensions always be alpha like in your example (besides the wildcards)?

Comment: they could also be mp4|mp3 for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct this from smaller building blocks. A single extension, excluding the characters you mention, would be:

```
[^\\<>/:"]+
```

We should probably also exclude `|` since that's our delimiter:

```
[^\\<>/:"|]+
```

This can automatically match wildcards as well, since they're not forbidden.

To construct the `|`-separated list from those is then easy:

```
[^\\<>/:"|]+
```

followed by an arbitrary number of the same thing with a `|` before that:

```
[^\\<>/:"|]+(\|[^\\<>/:"|]+)*
```

And if you want a complete string to match this, add the `^`  and `$` anchors:

```
^[^\\<>/:"|]+(\|[^\\<>/:"|]+)*$
```

Comment: I tried you suggestion but it failed to match when I added the first | delimiter to add a second file extension i.e. doc|xls

Comment: @Neil: Sorry, forgot to escape the `|`.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick, I also had to escape the `/` to get it to work in the online tester I am using.